# php-fpm access log should contain custom variables set from php application

Tags: php, nginx, openresty, access-log

## Pre

Current setup is made with apache+mod_php. We are able to put in apache access log userId and sessionId set from the code by using `apache_setenv` and then in access log we got:

```
"\"%{USER_ID}e\" \"%{SESSION_ID}e\""
```

This is necessary for us to be able to debug information easily based on access logs.

## Feature

Consider the following setup: php application that runs on php-fpm with nginx as a reverse proxy.

I want to move to move to containerised application that is using php-fpm and nginx. The problem is that I'm not table to log dynamic variables to nginx or php-fpm log using `$_ENV`. The data exists in the dump of `$_SERVER` but then is not accessible neither from `php-fpm` or `nginx-acces` log.

## Question

1. If Im able to set `fastcgi_param` in nginx from env variable that comes from application case is closed. Using lua in nginx with os.getenvvariable should do the trick?
2. In php-fpm access log format `%{userId}e` and `%{sessionId}e` despite the fact that they exist in `var_dump($_SERVER)`. If I pass from nginx `fastcgi_param` with static value I can access such environment variable in php-fpm.

Is there any other options to make this go or LUA in nginx is the only option. Currently I'm about to try out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution ended using custom http headers:

```php
header("UserId: 1");
header("SessionId: session_id");
```

and then in nginx access log

```
log_format main "$upstream_http_userid $upstream_http_sessionid";
```

in case of apache access log

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O %{UserId}o %{SessionId}o"
```